# Invoking the new NotifyOSD framework in C?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gtk, ubuntu-9.04

I want to make my GTK+ applications use the new notification area in Ubuntu. How can I do this? An example is shown below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iconocast.com](http://www.iconocast.com/EB000000000000112/E3/News1_0.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Is there an updated image? (The image link is now 404. Since this remains a valuable question, a new image link might be helpful to some people.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not on an Ubuntu box so I can't write out any examples.

But Ubuntu's [NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines) page has a lot of information.

Examples in C, C#, and Python.

Debain also has a [tutorial](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Creating_desktop_notifications) that should more or less have some commonality.

Basically your going to be tying into the NotifyOSD framework which leverages the Free Desktop Foundations [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) messaging system.

For development you'll need [libnotify](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/) ( [only online documentation I could find](http://www.galago-project.org/docs/api/libnotify/files.html) )

If you just want some quick results from the command line or to use in a shell script you can also use the **notify-send** command.

Usage:

```
notify-send [OPTION...] <SUMMARY> [BODY]
```

Example:

```
notify-send Test "Totally gnarly message bro"
```

Or you can specify an icon:

```
notify-send -i ../icon.jpg  Image "This is a sweet picture"
```

There are a bunch of other options, expire time, urgency level, category.

Ubuntu doesn't follow the Notification specification that closely, they don't honor alot of the options defined by the FSF. Don't be surprised if some things don't work with ubuntu's notifier that you see working with another notifier system.

Some Other resources:

- Ubuntu's [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) wiki page.
- ArsTechnica has a great [article](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2008/12/canonical-linux-notification-system.ars) on the new notification's system.
- Great [article](http://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2009/04/notification-disappointment-in-ubuntu.html) on some of the flaws in Ubuntu's notification's implementation.

Comment: I bet you used some crazy filters on google to find this stuff! Thanks! ;-)